# Dagger AndroidInjector cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I've done my Android projects MainActivity by means of the MVP pattern. So in my MainPresenter I want to inject a dynamic String, which then shall populate a TextView for instance:

```
class MyMainPresenter @Inject constructor(@StringForTextView dynamicString : String )
```

whereas the StringForTextView annotation qualifier is defined as:

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier
@Qualifier
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class StringForTextView
```

then I also have my Interface:

```
interface DynamicString {
    @NonNull fun getDynamicString() : String
}
```

which is implemented as:

```
data class SimpleDynamicString(val dynString: String) : DynamicString {
    override fun getDynamicString(): String { return dynString }
}
```

then in my module:

```
@Provides
@StringForTextView
static DynamicString provideDynamicString(Application application)
{
    return new SimpleDynamicString(application.getString(R.string.example_string));
}
```

The problem is, that I get an error

> Error:(51, 2) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>   @com.ralf.example.injection.qualifiers.StringForTextView
>   java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated
>   method.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing a `DynamicString` while expecting a regular `String` in the constructor. You should use `DynamicString` there as well:

```
class MyMainPresenter @Inject constructor(
    @StringForTextView dynamicString: DynamicString
)
```

Also, you might want to hols on to that injected value by making it a property with `val`.

Comment: 1. corrected String to DynamicString in constructor, thnx. 2. added private val. Now, getting similar error `SimpleDynamicString cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method`

Comment: Are you sure you're asking for a `DynamicString` and not a `SimpleDynamicString` in the constructor? Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: It was SimpleDynamicString, now I corrected to DynamicString and it works.. Thnx