# How can I make a Dagger2 injection nullable?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521957/dagger-androidinjector-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method) I inject a SimpleDynamicString object to my presenter in a MVP structure. To avoid a NullPointerException, I have to implement this.

```
@Provides
@StringForTextView
static DynamicString provideDynamicString(Application application)
{
    return new SimpleDynamicString(application.getString(R.string.example_string));
}
```

Since I would like to use this one as a library, I am forced to implement everywhere.

**Can I avoid this, so if (accidenataly or not) forgotten, no NullPointerException will happen?**

Comment: What is `SimpleDynamicString`? What do you expect to happen, when if it's accidentally is forgotten?

Comment: 1. See link in beginning. 2. Nothing shall happen. Now I get an exception, when not providing the @Provides annotation.

Comment: Can you post your `SimpleDynamicString` class?

Comment: @JoaquimLey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521957/dagger-androidinjector-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method

Comment: @JoaquimLey data class SimpleDynamicString(val dynString: String) : DynamicString {
    override fun getDynamicString(): String { return dynString }
}

Answer (score 2):

Your `DynamicString`'s provides method is unscoped. `StringForTextView` is a qualifier annotation (meaning that Dagger can understand which DynamicString you want *if you have more than one provides method*). Also currently, because of your provides method is unscoped, Dagger is creating new instances when you inject.

If you want to use same instance of the `DynamicString` anywhere in your application, you need to create a `Singleton` component, put this provides method into a `Singleton` module and make the method's scope `Singleton`. If you make it `Singleton`, you can write one provides method and inject anywhere.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {SingletonModule.class})
public interface SingletonComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        Builder singletonModule(SingletonModule singletonModule);

        SingletonComponent build();
    }

    void inject(YourClassToInject yourClassToInject);

}

@Module
public class SingletonModule {

    @StringForTextView // this is qualifier annotation
    @Singleton // this is scope annotation
    @Provides
    DynamicString provideDynamicString(Application application)
        return new SimpleDynamicString(application.getString(R.string.example_string));
    }
}
```

More information about scopes:

- https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-part-i-basic-principles-graph-dependencies-scopes-3dfd032ccd82
- https://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about an [optional binding](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide).

```
@BindsOptionalOf abstract CoffeeCozy optionalCozy();
```